# When do I call mixpanel.people.identify

Tags: mixpanel

How do I tell mixpanel the userID of my logged on user?

Do I need to call `mixpanel.people.identify()` everytime my user logs in, or only the first time that I'm creating them on mixpanel?

If only the first time, how does mixpanel know who to associate events to?

Also, once I have identified the person, will all events be tracable to that person, or do I need to call `people.set()` explicitly to track a generic event separately from a user-specific event?

Answer (score 4):

You should call `mixpanel.people.identify()` every time a user logs in. You can even call it every time a page loads in a logged in state if you want.

`identify` sets some data in a cookie about what `distinct_id` the library should use when sending people data.

<strike>If you have called `mixpanel.identify` with the same `distinct_id` as `mixpanel.people.identify`,</strike> events that you send (with `mixpanel.track`) will show up under the user's profile on the Customers tab. In order for the user to show up at all, though, you will need to call `mixpanel.people.set` (or `.add`) at least once.

EDIT: `mixpanel.people.identify` is no longer necessary; you can just call `mixpanel.identify` and it will set both.